# Pandas applying data subset to new data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script where I do munging with dataframes and extract data like the following:

```
times = pd.Series(df.loc[df['sy_x'].str.contains('AA'), ('t_diff')].quantile([.1, .25, .5, .75, .9]))
```

I want to add the resulting data from `quantile()` to a data frame with separate columns for each of those quantiles, lets say the columns are:

```
   ID pt_1 pt_2 pt_5 pt_7 pt_9
   AA
   BB
   CC
```

How might I add the quantiles to each row of ID?

```
new_df = None
for index, value in times.items():
   for col in df[['pt_1', 'pt_2','pt_5','pt_7','pt_9',]]:
```

..but that feels wrong and not idiomatic. Should I be using `loc` or `iloc`? I have a couple more Series that I'll need to add to other columns not shown, but I think I can figure that out once I know

EDIT:
Some of the output of `times` looks like:

```
0.1  -0.5
0.25 -0.3
0.5   0.0
0.75  2.0
0.90  4.0
```

Thanks in advance for any insight

Comment: can you show what df and times looks like?

Comment: @BenoitdeMenthière I added a snippet of it now. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

`pd.DataFrame(times.values.T, index=times.keys())`

Comment: I get an error with this as well: ```numpy.ndarray' object is not callable``` ?

Comment: my bad I thought times was a dict, i edited my answer

Comment: got another error ```concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'```

Comment: sorry, no need of concat

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want a `groupby()`:

```
# toy data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'sy_x':np.random.choice(['AA','BB','CC'], 100),
                   't_diff': np.random.randint(0,100,100)})

df.groupby('sy_x').t_diff.quantile((0.1,.25,.5,.75,.9)).unstack(1)
```

Output:

```
      0.10   0.25  0.50   0.75  0.90
sy_x                                
AA    16.5  22.25  57.0  77.00  94.5
BB     9.1  21.00  58.5  80.25  91.3
CC     9.7  23.25  40.5  65.75  84.1
```

Comment: I get an error trying that: ```index 136 is out of bounds for size 135```  ?

Comment: My code runs on the toy data. Can you share your `df`?

Comment: when I'm by my computer again ;)

Comment: I can tell you the rest of the cells have value nan. The df was made empty with just the IDs in the first row